# AutoCAD Map import MapInfo TAB file georeferencing info

Tags: mapinfo, georeferencing, import, autocad-map

Is there a way to import the TAB file created for georeferencing of an image by Mapinfo into AutoCAD so I don't have to do all the georeferencing again?

Comment: What image type is in question (jpg, tif, ecw, etc...) and which version of Autodesk map ?

Comment: Does it matter? They are PNGs and JPGs. Map is anything from 2015 to 2018. Unless there has actually been this added in it should be the same because Map never gets updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **`MAPIINSERT`** command in Autodesk Map and browse for raster image.

After that, Autodesk Map should automatically recognize present TAB file (it has 
to be with the same name as the image file) and it will be shown as a *Correlation Source* in Image Correlation dialogue:

[image]

Check the *units for insertion point* and after that check the coordinates in *Insertion* tab. If everything is alright map will be displayed in the right position.

[image]

Comment: Brilliant thanks. I was using IINSERT so no wonder. Will try on the next image.

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to GIS Stack Overflow. If this answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted. :)